# Oracle GetSchema() not returning package procedures

Tags: .net, oracle, ado.net, odp.net, getschema

I'm using GetSchema to load a list of procedures from my Oracle environment,  however I only see root procedures, no package procedures.  Looking through the documentation though, I don't see how else they could be returned.  Does anyone know if there is a filter/restriction to get package procs, or should I be calling a different object type?

```
Dim ObjectType= "Procedures"
Dim Options As String()

Dim ObjectsTable = OracleConnection.GetSchema(ObjectType, Options)
```

**Sample 'Packages' Results**

```
?RefinedPackageSchemaData(10)
Count = 12
    (0): {[OWNER, #REDACTED SCHEMA NAME#]}
    (1): {[OBJECT_NAME, #REDACTED PACKAGE NAME#]}
    (2): {[SUBOBJECT_NAME, ]}
    (3): {[OBJECT_ID, 130652]}
    (4): {[DATA_OBJECT_ID, ]}
    (5): {[LAST_DDL_TIME, 4/27/2015 3:52:26 PM]}
    (6): {[TIMESTAMP, 2015-04-27:15:52:26]}
    (7): {[STATUS, VALID]}
    (8): {[TEMPORARY, N]}
    (9): {[GENERATED, N]}
    (10): {[SECONDARY, N]}
    (11): {[CREATED, 1/9/2015 9:47:50 AM]}
```

The number of rows corresponds to exactly the number of packages, not package+procedure combinations

**Sample 'PackageBodies' Result**

```
 ?RefinedPackageBodySchemaData(10)
    Count = 12
        (0): {[OWNER, #REDACTED SCHEMA NAME#]}
        (1): {[OBJECT_NAME, #REDACTED PACKAGE NAME#]}
        (2): {[SUBOBJECT_NAME, ]}
        (3): {[OBJECT_ID, 130653]}
        (4): {[DATA_OBJECT_ID, ]}
        (5): {[LAST_DDL_TIME, 4/27/2015 4:19:44 PM]}
        (6): {[TIMESTAMP, 2015-04-27:16:19:44]}
        (7): {[STATUS, VALID]}
        (8): {[TEMPORARY, N]}
        (9): {[GENERATED, N]}
        (10): {[SECONDARY, N]}
        (11): {[CREATED, 1/9/2015 9:48:02 AM]}
```

The number of rows corresponds to exactly the number of packages, not package+procedure combinations

[MSDN Oracle GetSchema Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716723(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't you want the ObjectType to be "Packages"?  The public methods should be the `subobject_name` values.

Comment: @JustinCave at your suggestion I did try that, however I only get corresponding packages, not a full list of package-procedure combinations

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only way to do this is to query the Arguments or ProcedureParameters schema, and group the results, discarding the actual Argument/Parameter information.

I did it like this:

```
Dim ArgumentsSchemaData =
    GetSchemaDictionary(Connection, "Arguments", New String() {"#REDACTED SCHEMA NAME#"})

Dim GroupedArguments = (
    From ASD In ArgumentsSchemaData
    Let FullObjectName =
        String.Format("{0}.{1}", ASD("PACKAGE_NAME"), ASD("OBJECT_NAME"))
    Group ASD By FullObjectName Into ON_Group = Group
    Order By FullObjectName
    Select FullObjectName
    ).ToList
```

With a separate helper function to pivot from DataTable to a List of dictionaries:

```
 Private Shared Function GetSchemaDictionary(
        ByRef Connection As IDbConnection,
        ByVal ObjectType As String,
        ByRef Options As String()
        ) As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))

        Dim SchemaObjectsList = GetSchemaObjectsList(Connection, ObjectType, Options)

        Dim Columns = (
            From C In SchemaObjectsList.Columns
            Let ColumnName = C.ToString
            Select ColumnName
            ).ToList

        Return (
            From OL In SchemaObjectsList
            Select Columns.ToDictionary(
                Function(C) C,
                Function(C) OL.Item(C)
            )).ToList
    End Function
```